# How to close an app with a process running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, macos, performance

im learning python so i decided to make a pomodore timer app with a tkinter UI, when i start the timer i cant close the app only by console, i think i it can be solve by using threads but im not sure if it is the best option.

here is the code:

```
work_time=25*60
time_rest=5*60
BG_COLOR_work= "#f26419"
BG_COLOR_rest = "#86bbd8"
class window:
    def C_time(self,time1):
        self.state_str.set("working")
        self.change_color(BG_COLOR_work)
        self.window.update_idletasks()
        while time1>=0:
            mins,secs=divmod(tiempo,60)
            counter='{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins,secs)
            self.timer_str.set(counter)
            self.window.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(1)
            time1-=1
            if tiempo<=0:
                if self.state_str.get()=="working":
                    time1=time_rest
                    self.state_str.set("rest")
                    self.change_color(BG_COLOR_rest)
                else:
                    time1=work_time
                    self.change_color(BG_COLOR_work)
                    self.state_str.set("working")
```

Comment: Generally when working with and GUI in python, you put the GUI on one thread, and the logic on another thread. One option would be to keep your logic on the main thread, and put you GUI on a daemon thread. Daemon just means that when main thread ends it will also terminate daemon thread.

Comment: That's not the right way to solve this.  Your event handlers should NEVER run for a long time.  Instead, you should use the `after` function to call your callback every second.  The callback just updates the timer, does whatever state changes need to be made, calls `after` again to get another callback and exits.